# How to resolve dependencies across modules that use different versions of a library?

Tags: gradle, apache-spark, netty

I'm trying to add a spark module into my java gradle project, however, I'm using io.netty:netty-all:5.0.0.Alpha1 and spark 1.5.2 uses io.netty:netty-all:4.0.33.Final, unfortunately the alpha version isn't backwards compatible because of a constructor for PooledByteBufAllocator.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.<init>(ZIIIIIII)V
at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.createPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:122)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:105)
at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:78)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.init(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.initialize(BlockManager.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:528)
```

One option is for me to fork spark to use another constructor and hope the alpha version will work. Another is to somehow force transitive dependencies to resolve for a single module (the spark module) but it's not clear to me how to accomplish that.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes into my mind is OSGI. That said you should better not use the alpha version of netty and stick to a stable branch.